# The android emulator does't show the changes that occur in the code

Tags: react-native, android-emulator

I am knew in react native and I need to run a project. I used the following command in the folder of my project:

1- npm start

2- react-native run-android

However, I have a strange problem. Whenever I change any thing in the code, nothing happen in emulator and the emulator show me the previous thing!

I have done it with cell phone connected to the PC and see the same result!
I even stop the emulator and start it again but, I see the same problem. The emulator do not show any changes in the code and show a constant project. Can you help me?

**Update:**
As I shake the cell phone and reload it, I see the following red screen error:

```
Could not connect to development server.
```

Comment: Did you try to open dev menu and activate hot reloading? Shake your device to do so, can't remember how to do it in emulator.

Comment: @Poptocrack: Thanks for your reply. Yes, I did that, please check the question again, I have updated it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable either Live Reload or Hot Reloading. Within the simulator, you can access the menu with the `Cmd+M` combination or click the icon (see screenshot) then just choose the option you want.

[image: Android Simulator Menu Items]

Comment: Or just taping `Reload` from the developer menu above